# Why does the checkbox I added only show up on one page (the profile page) instead of all pages, despite the correct @match pattern?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am making a tampermonkey userscript. its purpose is to remove a dom element that displays user reputation points, which it does do, and the checkbox is to toggle it on and off, and that also works fine.

I added a checkbox to my tampermonkey script, but it only shows up on one page instead of all pages. I made sure to check the @match pattern in the metadata, and it should be correct and include the checkbox on all pages. I also tried waiting for the header to load before adding the checkbox, but it didn't solve the problem.

I even looked at another user's code that successfully added an icon consistently in the same header. I even added their code to my script, but then their icon didn't even show up. I need help finding out why the checkbox is not appearing on all pages.

this is the full code i have, its not long.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove Reputation
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Remove reputation points from user's profile. Navigate Kbin unbiased.
// @author       minnieo
// @match        https://kbin.social/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=kbin.social
// @grant        none
// @license      MIT
// ==/UserScript==

// Check if reputation removal is enabled
let repEnabled = localStorage.getItem('repEnabled') === 'true';

function reputation() {
  if (!repEnabled) {
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById('popover').addEventListener('openPopover', (e) => {
    const element = e.target;
    const liElement = element.querySelector('li:nth-child(2)');
    if (liElement)  {
      liElement.remove();
    }
  });

  document.querySelector('.section.user-info .info li:nth-child(2)').remove();
}

reputation();

// checkbox (toggle on and off)
const headerMenu = document.querySelectorAll('#header.header menu')[1];
const profileDropdown = headerMenu.querySelectorAll('li.dropdown')[2];
const repToggleCont = document.createElement('li');
const repToggle = document.createElement('a');
repToggle.className = repEnabled ? 'fa-solid fa-square-check' : 'fa-solid fa-square';
repToggle.title = repEnabled ? 'Show reputation (reloads page)' : 'Hide reputation';
repToggleCont.appendChild(repToggle)
headerMenu.appendChild(repToggleCont);
// insertAfter(repToggleCont, profileDropdown)

repToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  repEnabled = !repEnabled;
  localStorage.setItem('repEnabled', repEnabled);

  if (repEnabled) {
    repToggle.classList.replace('fa-square', 'fa-square-check');
    reputation();
  } else {
    repToggle.classList.replace('fa-square-check', 'fa-square');
    location.reload();
  }

  
});
```

my only issue is the checkbox itself not consistently showing up, or rather only showing on one page.

the other persons code which i pasted into mine just to test if it would work (it didnt, even though individually in its script it worked fine) is here:

```
var a_login = document.querySelector("#header a.login");
    var a_login_href = a_login.getAttribute("href");

    if (a_login_href !== "/login") {
        var subs_button = document.createElement("li");
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        var i = document.createElement("i");

        a.setAttribute("href", a_login_href + "/subscriptions");
        a.setAttribute("aria-label", "View subscriptions");
        a.setAttribute("title", "View subscriptions");
        a.className = "icon";

        i.className = "fa-solid fa-heart";

        a.appendChild(i);
        subs_button.appendChild(a);

        var menu = document.querySelectorAll("#header menu")[1];
        var search_button = menu.querySelector("li");
        menu.insertBefore(subs_button, search_button);
    }
```

I am trying to do this on https://kbin.social/. The checkbox only shows up on https://kbin.social/u/exampleusername

1. I tried waiting for the header to load before adding the checkbox, but it didn't solve the problem.
2. I even looked at another user's code that successfully added an icon consistently in the same header. I even added their code to my script, but then their icon didn't even show up
3. Waited for DOM content to load before running my script
4. Put a console.log at the beginning to see if it is running on all pages, it is running.

Comment: Is your code even running on the other pages? Add a `console.log()` call at the beginning to check this.

Comment: It is indeed running, Barmar.

Comment: Any errors? If the DOM weren't loaded you would get lots of errors because the query selectors won't return anything.

Comment: Add more console.log calls throughout the script, so you can see the values of the elements that you're selecting.

Comment: I'm not familiar with debugging tampermonkey scripts, but if you can use the JS debugger to set breakpoints and step through it, that would be the way to go.

Comment: There are no errors related to my script in the console. I added a console.log at the top of the script, it ran on all pages, however when I added another at the end of the script, that console.log didnt execute. I don't know why, the @match is correct

Comment: If `@match` weren't correct it wouldn't run the first console.log, so that's obviously right. Something else in the code is causing it to fail. That's why you need to single-step through it, or put console.log at multiple places to see where it stops.

Comment: I added a debugger after calling reputation();, and it only stopped on the profile page as expected

Comment: Then put it inside the `reputation()` function, so you can see why that's stopping it.

Comment: I added some debuggers. I found where it appears to stop running the code on all other pages, right before I call reputation();. like so:
debugger; // IT STOP HERE ON ALL OTHER PAGES

reputation();

Comment: Actually, it appears it does attempt to try and go through the function reputation(). it goes into it and stop right after if (!repEnabled) {
    return;
  }

Comment: More specifically now I see it the debugger stops the code right before the document.getElementById('popover').addEventListener part in the reputation function

Comment: I discovered the code will run when i remove this line from the function:
document.querySelector('.section.user-info .info li:nth-child(2)').remove();
i believe i left it over but it works when i remove it

Answer (score 0):

I left over a line that was causing this issue:

```
document.querySelector('.section.user-info .info li:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

Comment: Can you explain more about why this is a problem? As it is, this question isn't really very useful to future readers, since there's little context about what that's for and why it breaks it.

Comment: The only problem I can see is if the selector doesn't match anything. Then it should get an error because `querySelector()` will return `null`, which doesn't have a `.remove()` method. This should raise an error, but maybe TamperMonkey hides the error message.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).